# Adding subtitles to AirPlay video using AVFoundation on iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

Is there any way to make subtitles show over AirPlay on iOS using av `AVPlayer` with an`AVPlayerItem`? I've currently implemented subtitles by adding labels to the view hierarchy which works fine in the app, but that obviously doesn't work with AirPlay.

So, is there any way to display subtitles over AirPlay using `AVFoundation`?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you already implemented your own CC by creating a view for CC and adding it on top of the video. It will be easier to use AirPlay mirroring. You can do this by detecting an external screen and then place the content on it.

```
// detecting an external screen
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myExternalScreenDetected:) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];

//
// Grab external screen then add the content
- (void)myExternalScreenDetected:(UIScreen *)externalScreen {
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:externalScreen.bounds];

    // ...add content to the window...

    window.screen = externalScreen;
    window.hidden = NO;
}
```

Another option is to use native closed caption.This can be done by adding language files (WebVTT format) into the m3u8 playlist. I haven't tried this. It seems more complicated. You can take a look at the Apple's video here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=512

Mirroring feature seems easier to implement CC than the native way. However the native video airplay has better performance because the AppleTV loads the playlist file (m3u8) and plays the content directly. Mirroring AirPlay has to re-compress the output and send to AppleTV.

Comment: Mirroring has a horrible performance and videos will degrade towards slideshows.

Comment: It's not that bad. Hulu Plus uses mirroring. Not the best, but okay.

Answer (score -1):

You've probably already figured this out, but the reason your closed-captions aren't displaying when you airplay to Apple TV is probably that your AppleTV has closed captioning turned off.